# Fail2ban fail to start with several error messages

Tags: linux, fail2ban

I've installed `fail2ban` for my CentOS 6, but when it starts, I get the error message

```
Failed to start server : Starting fail2ban: WARNING 'ignoreregex' 
not defined in 'Definition'. Using default one: '' ERROR No file(s) 
found for glob /var/log/mail.log ERROR Failed during configuration: 
Have not found any log file for sasl-iptables jail [FAILED]
```

Does anyone how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the mail.log file doesn't exist. Perhaps CentOS by default uses a different name for the mail log file. Perhaps you should go and check /var/log. Perhaps you will be educated.

Comment: the mail is in /var/log/maillog, need to be changed at relative config